# Java Spring Boot: Retrun ManyToOne Attribute value (id) and url in _links

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am a newbie with to Java and Java Spring boot. I am building an REST Api. I have some `@ManyToOne`-relationships in my entity. The default of Spring Boot is to return the URL of the attribute in `_links`-section. Is there a simple way to return the attribute value additionally as "normal" attribute? I would be awesome if just have to make same changes in the entity class.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, not shure if this is the recommend way. I added an additional attributed and changed the `getter` to return the id of the `@ManyToOne`:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "MasterData_ID")
private MasterData masterData;

@JoinColumn(name = "MasterData_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private long masterData_ID;

public long getMasterData_ID() {
    return this.masterData.getMasterDataID();
}
```